# Use wp_dropdown_pages in theme options

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress

I am using `wp_dropdown_pages` in a WordPress theme options.
I have this code so far:

```
wp_dropdown_pages( array( 
    'name' => 'plugin_options[whatever_page]', 
    'show_option_none' => __( '— Select —' ), 
    'option_none_value' => '0', 
    'selected' => $options['whatever_page'] 
));
```

It works perfectly to show a selectbox of the pages and their `page_ID` as options' values.
Only one trouble I am having, after selecting a page and save settings, the page is not selected.
How can I save the selected page?

Comment: Can you provide the minimal code that a person need to replicate the problem? See [help/mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

The WP_Customize_Control class has a specified type 'dropdown-pages' already available

```
$wp_customize->add_section( 'section-slug' , array(
        'title' => __( 'section name', '_s' ),
        'priority' => 30,
        'description' => __( 'section description', '_s' )
) );
$wp_customize->add_setting( 'control-slug' , array());
$wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Control( $wp_customize, 'control-slug', array(
        'label'   => __( 'Page Link', 'theme-name' ),
        'section' => 'section-slug',
        'type'    => 'dropdown-pages',
        'settings' => 'control-slug',
) ) );
```